# Run CMD from C# Console Application?

Tags: c#, cmd

How might I run CMD.EXE from my C# Console Aplication? Like in Powershell you can run cmd.exe by typing "cmd"

EDIT: Open Powershell. Type "cmd". That's what I want.

EDIT2: Thank you for your help. I will try to make it clearer. I want it so that when the user enters "cmd" into my command line C# Application, it runs CMD.EXE in that same window. it is basically the same as typing CMD in Powershell.

Comment: What do you mean by "run cmd"? Start process? Open "Command line" window?

Comment: You could look into piping. Essentially you want the ouput from cmd pipend in your own shell and your shells input sent to cmd for execution.

Answer (score 4):

is `Process.Start("cmd.exe")` is what you're seeking for? (Don't forget to add  `using System.Diagnostics`))
More info about [Process class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: unfortunantly, there is no Process in a C# Console Application

Comment: see update) (add using directive or just use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe"))

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to open it in the same window?

Comment: I don't clearly get what you want to achieve. Do you want to redirect user's input to shell? Update the question, please, with information about your problem/idea.

Comment: What you seem to be looking for is writing your own shell. You don't need to start a "cmd.exe" for executing processes from your own commandline.

Comment: But is there any way to start CMD in my Console Application?

Comment: @Leonidas Aaaah) Couldn't resolve it from the question. Sorry)

Comment: @Matt You cannot start cmd in your console application. But you can read input lines from user, then execute them using Process.Start()

Comment: @Matt And don't forget to redirect output of that process to your window. For more info read MSDN articles about Process class

Answer (score 3):

I think that you want your user to have an interactive shell inside your application.

One way to do that is to redirect both stdin and stdout of cmd.exe to your application. It will input/output data from console in a string so you can show it in a textbox of whatever flots your boat.

[This project from code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ProcessStartDemo.aspx) seems to do what you want to do

Comment: Wasn't the answer I was looking for right now but very handy to know, thanks!